# How to create a shared object file from static library

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, shared-libraries

How to create a shared object file from a static library? I am using Cygwin.

Is the following syntax correct?

```
gcc -shared -o libexample.so libexample.a
```

Answer (score 16):

```
gcc -shared -o libexample.so -Wl,--whole-archive libexample.a
```

Pay attention that often you'll want the objects combined in your .so to be compiled as PIC, something you don't often want for a static library.

Comment: Is it also possible to go the other way around an create a static library from a shared object resp. collection of dependent shared objects?

Comment: Yes -- at least of Unix, a static library is an archive (thus the name .a) of object files with an index.

Comment: @AProgrammer and how to do the reverse process then (especially the index part)?

Answer (score 6):

It might not work but you can always try:

```
ar -x libexample.a
gcc -shared *.o -o libexample.so
```

If it complains about -fPIC, then it probably won't work.