# Creating shared object from static library whose object files were linked with -fPIC

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

For a project we are trying to create a shared object file that exports a set of functions specified in `libname.exports`. Of course we know that the object files from which the `.so` file gets linked have to be created using `-fPIC`, so that has been taken care of. We then combined the object files into an archive named `libname.a`. This should now be the basis for the `.so` file to be created - or so was the idea.

We're passing `libname.exports` to `--retain-symbols-file`, so the expected behavior was that the linker would pull in any of the `.a` members relevant to those symbols.

However, the output of `nm libname.so` is empty. On the other hand grepping in `nm libname.a` shows that the relevant symbols named in `libname.exports` exist in the `.a` members.

Now I stumbled over `--whole-archive` and thus adjusted the command line from:

```
gcc -o libname.so -shared -Wl,-z,defs,--retain-symbols-file,libname.exports,-L. libname.a -lc
```

to:

```
gcc -o libname.so -shared -Wl,-z,defs,--retain-symbols-file,libname.exports,-L.,--whole-archive,libname.a,--no-whole-archive -lc
```

which appears to have the intended effect of including *all* the object files from the `.a` (although the size difference is strange). However, `nm libname.so` still gives me no output.

How can I use the archive file to create a shared object with only the symbols named in `libname.exports` visible?

Unfortunately [How to create a shared object file from static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263780) doesn't quite answer my question.

Note: before you ask. The idea behind using the `.a` file as input is because it makes it easy to use a pattern rule in `GNUmakefile` and because the `.a` file with `-fPIC` is needed regardless. There shouldn't be any difference between linking the individual object files versus the archive file.

Comment: Have you _tried_ extracting and linking the separate object files?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: yes. That works as long as the `libname.exports` contains the symbol names to be exported and `libname.a` contains the respective members. What I did as a test is to `ar x libname.a` into a subfolder `armembers` and then pass `armembers/*.o` on the command line instead of `libname.a`.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193944/convert-a-static-library-to-a-shared-library-create-libsome-so-from-libsome-a

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-u SYMBOL` option to force objects to be read in from an archive.

```
% cc -c -fPIC a.c
% nm a.o
00000000 T a
% ar rv liba.a a.o
ar: creating liba.a
a - a.o
% gcc -o liba.so -shared -u a liba.a
% nm liba.so | awk '$3 == "a" { print }'
0000042c T a
```

One thing to check would be the spellings of the symbols being specified with `--retain-symbols-file`.  For example, symbol names in objects compiled from C++ code are likely to be mangled:

```
% g++ -c -fPIC a.c
% nm a.o | awk '$2 == "T" { print }'
00000000 T _Z1av
```

Comment: thanks. It's C-files and I'm aware of the mangling. Let me see whether `-u` will do the job. Because for all I know, I want to pull in some API functions (named in said file) and could simply use the file to create a command line. I checked the spelling of the symbols, btw. Unfortunately it's not the problem.