# why does "g++ -shared foobar.a" lose symbols?

Tags: g++

If I do

`>ar rc foobar.a foobar.o`

`>g++ -shared -fPIC foobar.a -o foobar.so`

the resulting `foobar.so` is much smaller and has missing symbols compared to

`>g++ -shared -fPIC foobar.o -o foobar.so`

where `foobar.so` has all the symbols from `foobar.o`

Why?

SSCCE as requested by Alec Teal:

```
> cat foobar.cpp
#include "foobar.h"

Foobar::Foobar() {}

> cat foobar.h
class Foobar {
public:
    Foobar();
};

> g++ -fPIC -c foobar.cpp -o foobar.o
> ar rc foobar.a foobar.o
> nm foobar.a | grep Foobar
0000000000000000 T _ZN6FoobarC1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN6FoobarC2Ev
> g++ -fPIC -shared foobar.a -o foobar.so
> nm foobar.so | grep Foobar
> g++ -fPIC -shared foobar.o -o foobar.so
> nm foobar.so | grep Foobar
0000000000000680 T _ZN6FoobarC1Ev
0000000000000680 T _ZN6FoobarC2Ev
```

tristan's answer points to the usage of `--whole-archive` option, does not work for me:

```
> g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,--whole-archive foobar.a  -o foobar.so
/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against     undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_end' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Need more info, but everything will work, if GCC has dropped symbols it has done so legitimately, fear not. If you want to know why rather than just trusting, please add details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601302/creating-shared-object-from-static-library-whose-object-files-were-linked-with